# Openresty concurrent requests

Tags: multithreading, nginx, lua, openresty

I would like to use OpenResty with Lua interpreter.

I can't make the OpenResty framework to handle two concurrent requests to two separate endpoints. I simulate that one request is doing some hard calculations by running in a long loop:

```
local function busyWaiting()
    local self = coroutine.running()
    local i = 1
    while i < 9999999 do
        i = i + 1
        coroutine.yield(self)
    end
end

local self = coroutine.running()
local thread = ngx.thread.spawn(busyWaiting)

while (coroutine.status(thread) ~= 'zombie') do
    coroutine.yield(self)
end


ngx.say('test1!')
```

The other endpoint just sends response immediately.
`ngx.say('test2')`

I send a request to the first endpoint and then I send a second request to the second endpoint. However, the OpenResty is blocked by the first request and so I receive both responses almost at the same time.

Setting nginx parameter `worker_processes  1;` to higher number does not help either and I would like to have only single worker process anyway.

What is the proper way to let OpenResty handle additional requests and not to get blocked by the first request?

Comment: You don't provide any code showing us how do you send subrequests. I assume that you use something like ngx.location.capture for sending subrequests to endpoints.  You should use https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxlocationcapture_multi API for subrequests running in parallel.

Comment: I am not using ngx.location.capture. I use two separate clients to connect to two different endpoints on the same server.

Comment: @JeFi sorry, did not understand your use case, now it is clear, see my answer below

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @MappaM , unfortunately I did not.

Answer (score 0):

```
local function busyWaiting()
    local self = ngx.coroutine.running()
    local i = 1
    while i < 9999999 do
        i = i + 1
        ngx.coroutine.yield(self)
    end
end

local thread = ngx.thread.spawn(busyWaiting)

while (ngx.coroutine.status(thread) ~= 'dead') do
    ngx.coroutine.resume(thread)
end


ngx.say('test1!')
```

Comment: Changing `coroutine.yield` to `coroutine.resume` in second while loop does not cause the interpreter to continue with the coroutine incrementing variable `i`. Variable `i` gets incremented only to value 2. The second while loop then becomes infinite.

Comment: Sorry, you are working in Openresty context, add "ngx." prefix to all API

Comment: ngx.coroutine does not exist, and this answer does not solve the problem...

Comment: @MappaM you are funny, https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#lua-coroutine-yieldingresuming

Comment: You should explain in your answer what you changed and why you think it should work. Maybe it is because I tried using the standard version of NGINX+Lua and not the one from Openresty. In which coroutine is the main package name. ngx.coroutine does not exists and gives an error. And using coroutine.yield does not solve the problem at hand, the server will not serve another request even when yielding.

Comment: @MappaM the question is about OpenResty